# How does Google Analytics handle parameters that are too long

Tags: google-analytics

Tag Assistant plugin is giving a warning that custom dimension parameter is too long, since it's been like that for quite a while I would like to asses how the data was impacted.
Does anyone know how Analytics will handle a request with a property that is too long? Does the entire event get dropped, only the too long property, or it gets trimmed.

Someone asked an identical question here but it got no answer:
https://support.google.com/tagmanager/thread/15716265?hl=en

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its not programming related may be better suited for https://webapps.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Custom dimension max length is 150 Bytes (150 characters):

[image]

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/field-reference#dimension

However I had fun doing a test with the hit builder (https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/hit-builder/) on one of my Analytics Properties. I entered a number of allowed characters and initially received a warning message:

> The value provided for parameter 'cd1' is over the recommended limit.

however, I managed to send the hits with a different number of characters as value for the custom dimension:

- 150 characters (limit declared in Google documentation)
- 300 characters
- 600 characters
- 1200 characters
- 2400 characters
- 4800 characters
- 8107 characters (limit beyond which the hit builder returned an error and did not validate the hit)

The result in Google analytics was the following:

[image]

So I would say that the answer is .... **the limits are made to be overcome** :)

Comment: Yeah I was looking into my data, and it seems like there are hits with longer than 150 bytes values. But I wonder then what exactly does a "warning" mean, can I safely ignore it, maybe some throttling appears on bigger loads, maybe it works now but google is free to change it any moment without a warning. Etc.
I'll wait a bit more before marking this as an answer.

Comment: The data in Google Analytics can be considered stable after at least 48h. I just checked and I confirm that all the values ​​of the custom dimension are still there, even if they have exceeded the recommended limits by a lot :)